# Using passport-jwt and epilogue, my req.user is empty

Tags: jwt, passport.js, epilogue, passport-jwt

My middleware code is:

```
exports.isAuthenticated = (req, res, context) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return passport.authenticate('jwt',{session: false}, (err, user, info) => {
      if(err) {
        res.status(500).send({message: 'Internal Server Error'})
        return resolve(context.stop);
      }

      if(user) {
        return resolve(context.continue);
      } else {
        res.status(401).send({message: 'Unauthorized'})

        return resolve(context.stop)
      }
    })(req, res);
  }); 
}
```

My epilogue code is:

```
// Data plan REST API
const dataplan = epilogue.resource({
  model: global.db.DataPlan,
  endpoints: ['/api/dataplan', '/api/dataplan/:id']
});

dataplan.all.auth(middleware.isAuthenticated)
dataplan.use(require('./epilogue/dataplan.js'))
```

And my `dataplan.js` is:

```
module.exports = {
    list: {
      auth: async function (req, res, context) {
        console.log(req.user)
        return context.continue
      },
      send: {
       ....
```

But my `req.user` is empty in my `list.auth`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think you can use `async` functions here, because it seems to based on express which expects normal function to be middleware

Comment: Try using this package that will allow you to use async in your express functions : https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-errors

Comment: Have you tried printing something in your middleware to make sure it is called when you expect it to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

`passport.authenticate` doesn't set `req.user` if you provide a callback to it. You have to set it yourself.

## Solution

I was able to reproduce your case and the behavior showed up as expected.

In order to fix it, I had to update your auth middleware like so:

```
exports.isAuthenticated = (req, res, context) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return passport.authenticate('jwt',{session: false}, (err, user, info) => {
      if(err) {
        res.status(500).send({message: 'Internal Server Error'})
        return resolve(context.stop);
      }

      if(user) {
        req.user = user; // Manually set the user in req
        return resolve(context.continue);
      } else {
        res.status(401).send({message: 'Unauthorized'})

        return resolve(context.stop)
      }
    })(req, res);
  }); 
}
```

I manually assign `user` to `req.user` when authentication is successful. This properly fixes the issue.

## Why does this happen?

By looking at the [passport source code](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/9502d99/lib/middleware/authenticate.js#L213) I notice that the `passport.authenticate` function will short circuit itself if the user provides a callback himself.
This means that you have to set the value yourself.